# Stream all audio from Windows machine to HTTP browser client

Tags: windows, http, browser, audio-streaming

So far I was able to do something similar using SoundWire (http://georgielabs.cjb.net/) with a windows machine (server) and an android phone (client).

Now, I'd like to stream all playback audio from a Windows machine to any device capable of opening a web page (using flash/html5 audio tag).
The closest thing I could find was BroadWave (http://www.nch.com.au/streaming/index.html), but I didn't work inside my android browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Icecast + Edcast should work if I could select playback devices from Edcast instead of only record devices. Unfortunately "Stereo Mix" is not avaiable for me.

Comment: There are audio loopback drivers.  Is this something you want to implement in your application?  Or are you trying to use other applications?

Comment: @Brad I'm just trying to use it. The audio loopback drivers seems to fix the lack of Stereo Mix. If no other solution without relying to record devices is found Ill try this, thanks.